# Having trouble with a PostgreSQL query

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've got the following two tables:

**User**

```
userid | email | phone  
1 | some@email.com | 555-555-5555  
2 | some@otheremail.com | 555-444-3333  
3 | one@moreemail.com | 333-444-1111
4 | last@one.com | 123-333-2123
```

**UserTag**

```
id | user_id | tag  
1 | 1 | tag1  
2 | 1 | tag2  
3 | 1 | cool_tag  
4 | 1 | some_tag  
5 | 2 | new_tag  
6 | 2 | foo  
6 | 4 | tag1
```

I want to run a query in SQLAlchemy to join those two tables and return all users who do NOT have the tags "tag1" or "tag2". In this case, the query should return users with userid 2, and 3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I need the opposite of this query:

```py
users.join(UserTag, User.userid == UserTag.user_id)
    .filter(
        or_(
            UserTag.tag.like('tag1'),
            UserTag.tag.like('tag2')
        ))
    )
```

I have been going at this for hours but always end up with the wrong users or sometimes all of them. An SQL query which achieves this would also be helpful. I'll try to convert that to SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how this would look in SQLAlchemy, but hopefully and explanation of why the query is the way it is will help you get there.

This is an outer join - you want all the records from one table (User) even if there are no records in the other table (UserTag) if we put User first it would be a left join. Beyond that you want all the records that don't have a match in the UserTag for a specific filter.

```
SELECT user.user_id, email, phone
  FROM user LEFT JOIN usertag
  ON usertag.user_id = user.user_id
    AND usertag.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2')
  WHERE usertag.user_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL will go like this

```
select u.* from user u join usertag ut on u.id = ut.user_id and ut.tag not in ('tag1', 'tag2');
```

I have not used SQLAlchemy so you need to convert it to equivalent SQLAlchemy query.

Hope it helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model defines a relationship as below:

```
class User(Base):
    ...

class UserTag(Base):
    ...
    user = relationship("User", backref="tags")
```

the query follows:

```
qry = session.query(User).filter(~User.tags.any(UserTag.tag.in_(tags))).order_by(User.id)
```